# C# problem with BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I have a problem with a component "BackgroundWorker"

When I click on a button I have to perform n iterations that take time and I have to delegate this operation to another thread

I followed this tutorial: [tutorial (in french)](http://www.developpez.net/forums/d311839/dotnet/developpement-windows/windows-forms/csharp-threads-probleme-backgroundworker/)

Here is my code:

```
    private void btnIterate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bgwIterer.RunWorkerAsync();                
    }

    private void bgwIterer_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
        e.Result = new Iterate(btnIterate, btnReinit, txtInput, lblState, entree, worker, e);
    }

    private void bgwIterer_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.lblState.Text = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }
```

bgwIterer is my BackgroundWorker component
and here is the method I would like to delegate:

> ```
> class Iterate
> {
>     // Constructeur surchargé de la classe Iterate:
>     public Iterate(Button mybtnIterate, Button mybtnReinit,
>     TextBox mytxtInput, Label mylblState,
>     int myentree, BackgroundWorker worker,
>     DoWorkEventArgs e)
>     {
>         int pourcent = 0;
>         int var0 = 0, var1;
>         mybtnIterate.Enabled = false;
>         mytxtInput.Focus();
>         do
>         {
>             var1 = 0;
>             do
>             {
>                 ++var1;
>             }
>             while (var1 < myentree);
>             ++var0;
>             pourcent = (var0 / myentree) * 100;
>             worker.ReportProgress(pourcent);
>         }
>         while (var0 < myentree);
>         mylblState.Text = "Terminé !";
>         mytxtInput.Enabled = false;
>     }
> ```
>
> }

and this is the problem:

**The type or namespace name 'BackGroundWorker' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

Does someone have an idea?

Comment: What does your namespace declarations look like, what version of .NET are you using and and in particular are you referencing System.ComponentModel.Component? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

Comment: Have you added a using for System.ComponentModel?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to add:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
```

Answer (score 2):

Class name is BackgroundWorker, not BackGroundWorker - that's why.

Comment: That's strange I used BackgroundWorker :/

Comment: I just looked at the error you posted - it has capital "G". But anyway, looks like it wasn't the real issue - you simply had to add a "using" statement :)